# XNA - how to tell if a thumb stick was "twitched" in a certain direction

Tags: input, xna

Is there anything in the API (3 or 4) to tell me if the stick moved in one direction, as in a menu where it's equivalent to hitting a direction on the DPad? There appear to be some `Thumbstick*` members in the `Buttons` enum, but I can't find decent documentation on them.

Just want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious before I go and roll my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no XNA method to tell you if a thumbstick was "twitched" this frame.

The easiest method is to store the old thumbstick state.  If the state was zero and is now non-zero, it has been twitched.

**Addition:**

Instead of checking if the state was zero and is now non-zero.  You can use the thumbstick buttons from the enumeration you mention in your question to determine if the stick has been "twitched".  In this case you are treating the stick like a DPad and have to test each direction independently.  The following code shows this method:

```
private void ProcessUserInput()
{
    GamePadState gamePadState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

    if (m_lastGamePadState.IsButtonUp(Buttons.LeftThumbstickUp) && gamePadState.IsButtonDown(Buttons.LeftThumbstickUp))
    {
        PrevMenuItem();
    }

    if (m_lastGamePadState.IsButtonUp(Buttons.LeftThumbstickDown) && gamePadState.IsButtonDown(Buttons.LeftThumbstickDown))
    {
        NextMenuItem();
    }

    m_lastGamePadState = gamePadState;
}
```

Comment: While this is the right idea, the threshold needs to be above zero (for use in menus), and there needs to be a margin between activation and deactivation to prevent it flicking (see my answer).

Comment: I'm not that sure you are right.  I opened a new question about this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075945/is-a-non-zero-threshold-required-to-prevent-flicking-when-reading-the-xbox360-thu.

Comment: Added cleaner method of detecting a "flick" in the stick thanks to Martin Stone's answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

The thumbsticks on an Xbox 360 controller can be pushed "in" like buttons, which map to `GamePadButtons.LeftStick` and `GamePadButtons.RightStick`. These are obviously **not** what you want.

Here is the code that I use for detecting "presses" in *any* direction (where `padLeftPushActive` is stored between frames):

```
Vector2 padLeftVector = gamePadState.ThumbSticks.Left;
bool lastPadLeftPushActive = padLeftPushActive;
if(padLeftVector.Length() > 0.85f)
    padLeftPushActive = true;
else if(padLeftVector.Length() < 0.75f)
    padLeftPushActive = false;

if(!lastPadLeftPushActive && padLeftPushActive)
{
    DoSomething(Vector2.Normalize(padLeftVector));
}
```

It should be fairly simple to modify this so that it detects just presses in the particular directions necessary for your menu.

Comment: Looks like he was talking about the Buttons enumeration not the GamePadButtons enumeration.  Buttons contains LeftThumbstickUp, LeftThumbstickDown, LeftThumbstickLeft, LeftThumbstickRight etc.  These are used with GamePadState.IsButtonUp and GamePadState.IsButtonDown and allow you to treat the thumbstick as if it were a DPad.

Comment: Ah - you're quite right. I thought that API existed, and was surprised that I couldn't find it. Seems I was looking in the wrong spot. Nevertheless, I'll leave my answer here in case people find it useful. There's also some more discussion the merits of custom coding this input handler in [my answer to your discussion question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075945/is-a-non-zero-threshold-required-to-prevent-flicking-when-reading-the-xbox360-thu/5077703#5077703).

Answer (score 0):

Is the [GamePadState.Thumbsticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.gamepadstate.thumbsticks.aspx) property what you're looking for?

Comment: no, that struct tells me where they are, but not what they've done. That's what I'll be using if nothing existing pops up, though. And I'll be sure to share it =P

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with, in case it's useful for anyone:

```
    enum Stick {
        Left,
        Right,
    }
    GamePadState oldState;
    GamePadState newState;

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if a thumbstick was quickly tapped in a certain direction. 
    /// This is useful for navigating menus and other situations where
    /// we treat a thumbstick as a D-Pad.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="which">Which stick to check: left or right</param>
    /// <param name="direction">A vector in the direction to check. 
    /// The length, which should be between 0.0 and 1.0, determines 
    /// the threshold.</param>
    /// <returns>True if a twitch was detected</returns>
    public bool WasStickTwitched(Stick which, Vector2 direction)
    {
        if (direction.X == 0 && direction.Y == 0)
            return false;

        Vector2 sold, snew;
        if (which == Stick.Left)
        {
            sold = oldState.ThumbSticks.Left;
            snew = newState.ThumbSticks.Left;
        }
        else
        {
            sold = oldState.ThumbSticks.Right;
            snew = newState.ThumbSticks.Right;
        }

        Vector2 twitch = snew;
        bool x = (direction.X == 0 || twitch.X / direction.X > 1);
        bool y = (direction.Y == 0 || twitch.Y / direction.Y > 1);
        bool tnew = x && y;

        twitch = sold;
        x      = (direction.X == 0 || twitch.X / direction.X > 1);
        y      = (direction.Y == 0 || twitch.Y / direction.Y > 1);
        bool told = x && y;

        return tnew && !told;
    }
```